# vulkaninfo failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: nvidia, vulkan

```
OS: ubuntu 18.04
GPU: Geforce GTX 1060
Driver: Nvidia Driver 440.82
Vulkan Package: libvulkan1/bionic-updates,now 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
```

Nvidia-smi shows the configuration correctly.

However, when i invoke vulkaninfo, I get /build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

It seems vulkan can not detect physical device. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might invoke `vulkaninfo` via the ssh terminal, just run on you physical device may solve it.